# PHP-Excel How can I pass Value from Php to Excel on a single column

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I'm trying to get the top bidder the sql work, unfortunately when I try downloading excel it only shows header and $report is not displaying on column 'A2' Thank you in Advance.

Here's the MODEL:

```
 function getTopBidder($datefrom, $dateto){
        $report4 = mysql_query("SELECT a.winner_id AS  'Users Id', u.first_name AS  'First Name', u.last_name AS  'Last Name', COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Auctions Won'
                            FROM auctions a
                            RIGHT JOIN users u ON a.winner_id = u.id
                            WHERE a.closed =  '1' AND a.end_time 
                            BETWEEN '".$dateFrom." 00:00:00' AND '".$dateTo." 23:59:59'
                            GROUP BY a.winner_id
                            ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                            LIMIT 1");

    return($report4);
    }
```

Here's my CTP :

```
 <form method='POST' action="">
 <h2><?php __('Top Bidder:');?></h2>
  From:<input name='daterange5' id='datepicker5' value='<?php echo $date; ?>'></input>
 To:<input name='daterange6' id='datepicker6' value='<?php echo $date; ?>'></input>
 <br />
 <input name='hidden' type='hidden' value='topBidder' />
 <input type='submit' value='Download' />
 </form>
```

Here's My Controller:

```
 function admin_reports(){
 App::import('Vendor', 'phpexcel',array('file' => 'phpexcel/PHPExcel.php'));
 if(!empty($this->params['form'])){
 ($this->params['form']['hidden'] == 'topBidder'){
            //$report = $this->Bid->getWonAuction($this->params['form']['daterange3'],$this->params['form']['daterange4']);
            $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

            $report4 = $this->Bid->getTopBidder($this->params['form']['daterange5'],$this->params['form']['daterange6']);

            //var_dump($report4);

            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                        ->setCellValue('A1','USER ID')
                        ->setCellValue('B1','FIRST NAME')
                        ->setCellValue('C1','LAST NAME')
                        ->setCellValue('D1','NUMBER OF AUCTION WON')
                        ->setCellValue('A2', $report4);


            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
            // Redirect output to a clientâ€™s web browser (Excel5)
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="topbidder.xls"');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
            // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

            // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
            header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
            header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
            header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
            header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
            $objWriter->save('php://output');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ok now I just forgot to capital datefrom, $dateto silly me, how to delete this question?